# Calling a non templated function from a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Hy. My question is that, I have a templated function in a .h file and inside i want to call a function which was not implemented any templates, it's just a basic "declaration and definiton" func. It's possible to call a non-templated function from a templated one?

.h file

```
template <typename T>
void func(T &param){

   //do something...

   int p=func2(some param);
}
```

.cpp file

```
int func2(some param){
   int a;

   //do something..

   return a;
}
```

I got an error code: there are no arguments to ‘func2’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘func2’ must be available

Comment: Have you declared `func2` in the .h file?

Comment: Remove the template and you'll get approximately the same error. The template is irrelevant.

Comment: You do remember to declare `func2` before you attempt to call it?

Comment: i found out the problem

Comment: the declaration of the func2 was after than the templated one

Answer (score 0):

After hours of googling i found the answer:
In my .h file the

`int func2(some param)`

was declared after than the templated funcion. So the compiler did not see it.
So correctly it looks like this:

```
int func2(some param);


template <typename T>
 void func(T &param){

   //do something...

   int p=func2(some param);
}
```